# Stokes Theorem on a Hemisphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

I have a question about Stokes Theorem. It's really confusing me.

So the problem asks,

Use Stokes theorem to set up the integral
$$\int_{a}^{b}g(t)dt$$
that you would use to compute
$$\iint_{S}^{}(\nabla\times \vec{F})\cdot d\vec{S}$$
where
$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\left \langle e^zsin(y),ze^x,2xcos(y) \right \rangle$$

and S is the hemisphere $y=\sqrt{9-x^2-z^2}$ oriented in the direction of the positive y-axis.

What I did was first calculate the curl:

$$\nabla\times \vec{F}=\left \langle -2xsin(y)-e^zcos(y),e^zsin(y)-2cos(y),ze^x-e^zcos(y) \right \rangle$$

Skipping steps,I have
$$\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x}\times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial z}
=\left \langle -\frac{x}{\sqrt{9-x^2-z^2}},-1,-\frac{z}{\sqrt{9-x^2-z^2}} \right \rangle=\vec{n}$$

$$\hat{n}=\left \langle -\frac{x}{3},-\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2-z^2}}{3},-\frac{z}{3} \right \rangle$$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Stokes' Theorem,

$\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_S curl \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S}$

which allows you to change the surface integral of the curl of the vector field to the line integral of the vector field around the boundary of the surface. The surface is hemisphere with $y = 0$ plane being the boundary, though the question should have been more clear on that. Also the question states we have orientation in positive $y$ direction.

By the way, there is a hint in the question to do line integral to find surface integral of the curl of the vector field.

Now we can parametrize the boundary as,

$\vec{r}(t) = (3 \cos t, 0, 3 \sin t) \,$ (as $y = 0$, it is a circle in $XZ$ plane with radius $3,$ $x^2 + z^2 = 9$)

$\vec{r'}(t) = (-3 \sin t, 0, 3 \cos t) \, $ ($0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi)$

Now substitute $x, y, z$ from above parametrization of the curve to evaluate $\vec{F}(r(t))$ and do the dot product with $\vec{r'}(t)$. Then do line integral wrt $dt$.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't this end up being zero?

Comment: It is not a conservative vector field so I don't think so. Need to evaluate. Did you do the dot product? What did it come to?

Comment: I had messed something up, just woke up. I didn't use $\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))$. I'll be able to figure it out now. I ended up getting $18\pi $ at the end, using the fact that $$cos^2t=\frac{1+cos(2t)}{2}$$ Question though. Was my approach beforehand still accurate if I wanted to solve using the curl version of Stokes' Theorem?

Comment: Yes that was the correct approach if you wanted to use the curl. But your cross product was not correct. Also you should have changed your unit normal vector to have positive $y$. At the end, the problem is that it would have been a tough integral given how the vector field is. So you need to always check which one is easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see now. I should have done $$\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial z}\times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial x}$$ to get a vector in the opposite direction, which would make y be positive.

Comment: or you can reverse the sign of all $3$ components after you get the normal vector, stating why. This was about the normal vector. Sorry on the cross product I meant when you found curl. Wrote incorrectly. The curl is not correct. Some mistake somewhere.